# Java regex and sed aren't the same...?

Tags: regex, string, sed

Get these strings:

```
00543515703528
00582124628575
0034911320020
0034911320020
005217721320739
0902345623
067913187056
00543515703528
```

Apply this exp in java: `^(06700|067|00)([0-9]*)`.

My intention is to remove leading *"06700, 067 and 00"* from the beggining of the string.

It is all cool in java, group 2 always have the number I intend to, but in `sed` it isnt the same:

```
$ cat strings|sed -e 's/^\(06700|067|00\)\([0-9]*\)/\2/g'
00543515703528
00582124628575
0034911320020
0034911320020
005217721320739
0902345623
067913187056
00543515703528
```

What the heck am I missing?

Cheers,

f.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using extended regular expressions, you also need to omit the `\` before `(` and `)`.  This works for me:

```
sed -r 's/^(06700|067|00)([0-9]*)/\2/g' strings
```

note also that there's no need for a separate call to `cat`

Answer (score 3):

I believe your problem is this:

> sed defaults to BRE: The default
>   behaviour of sed is to support Basic
>   Regular Expressions (BRE). To use all
>   the features described on this page
>   set the -r (Linux) or -E (BSD) flag to
>   use Extended Regular Expressions

[Source](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#sed)

Without this flag, the | character is interpreted literally. Try this example:

```
echo "06700|067|0055555" | sed -e 's/^\(06700|067|00\)\([0-9]*\)/\2/g'
```